# Printing refusing to print, citing non-genuine cartridges?

Tags: software

So I just got a Da-Vinci 3-in-1 Junior Pro 3D Printer, and was excited to start printing my first model.

When I open my .STL File in the XYZWare that comes with the printer, and click print, it says that the cartridge inserted into my printer in not genuine, and that it won't print until I order a genuine cartridge. What is interesting is that the cartridge loaded into this printer came with the printer itself, so it is genuine.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Here is a picture of the cartridge in my printer -->

[image: This is how the cartridge is sitting inside the printer housing]

A Google search about this issue doesn't come up with any results that are of any use to me.

Comment: Considering it is a brand new printer you could ask the seller/supplier for support. Alternatively, call the manufacturer.

Comment: This is an eery echo of the "genuine cartridge" disasters of several ink-jet (paper) printers over the last decade.   The proper answer is: Boycott any vendor who has a lock-in like this.  It exists only to maximize their profit.

Comment: XYZPrinting is a highly unethical company that's done a lot of other nasty stuff too, including baseless takedowns (false patent infringement claims) against sellers of their competitors' products on Amazon. Seriously, boycott them.

Comment: Return printer to retailer. If they won't take it, chargeback time. The printer was designed to be defective and not disclosed to be defective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to troubleshoot my printer's dilemma, rather quickly I might add.

It turns out that the printer's firmware that was shipped with the printer was too old for XYZWare to use. My theory was that the firmware was trying to use a sensor that wasn't on the printer to begin with, and therefore was throwing out the issue of non-genuine cartridges.

I updated the firmware on the Printer, and know it works just fine without any hitch!

Answer (score 5):

A [quick search on the internet](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Da-Vinci+3-in-1+Junior+Pro+3D+does+not+recognise+genuine+cartridge&rlz=1C1GCEA_en&oq=Da-Vinci+3-in-1+Junior+Pro+3D+does+not+recognise+genuine+cartridge&aqs=chrome..69i57.13982j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) showed that your experiences are shared by others.

Apparently, it has something to do with a faulty chip or the software.

From [this thread](https://www.3dhubs.com/talk/t/xyzprinting-aio-filament-cartridge-not-being-detected/4340):

> I had the same thing, the cop on the underside of the cartridge wasn’t
> programmed properly, if you have the latest firmware update and it
> still doesn’t work contact the seller and they should send you a
> replacement chip

> I had this happen 2x. It ended up being that I had xyzware open.
> Xyzware needs to restart in order to detect the new serial number of
> the filament.

You could ask for support from your supplier or restart the XYZ software.

You could also [hack](https://www.instructables.com/id/XYZ-Da-Vinci-Junior-jr-NFC-Tag-Filament-Reset-Hack/) the NFC chip that is inside the spool. (**DISCLAIMER**: *Do it at your own risk*!)